# Cannot modify global variable in function in PineScript

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, pine-script-v4

This is my Pinescript code.

```
//@version=5
indicator("Strategy", overlay=false)

var count = 0
count := nz(count[1],0)

counter() =>
    count := close > close[1] ? count + 1 : count

counter()

plot(count)
```

Here I am facing an issue in my counter function. I am getting an error in the count inside my counter function.
Cannot modify global variable 'count' in function; error displaying in Pinescript compiler.
I tried with Var also. still facing the same issue. Please help me to resolve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `count` variable should be defined *inside* of the function. Also, the `count` variable will not be available outside of the function.

The following will work:

```
//@version=5
indicator("Strategy", overlay=false)

counter() =>
    var count = 0
    count := nz(count[1],0)
    count := close > close[1] ? count + 1 : count
    count

new_count = counter()

plot(new_count)
```